# Beamer does not render custom `endpage` template when notes are enabled

Tags: beamer, frame

Recently I built my first LaTeX beamer theme.

The theme is open-source and available at https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/ (*It has an integration with Nix so anyone willing to create document with LaTeX or Pandoc can quickly setup its environment with one single command*)

The theme is also available on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/european-commission/qtzkhyvfxbrw

An example of document produced with it can be found here: https://github.com/ecphp/session--complexity-and-monads/releases/download/v11-c200d1f/11--complexity-and-monads--c200d1f.pdf

I'm opening this question because I noticed something while working with `\notes{}`. When I enable them as such:

```
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}
```

the custom beamer theme template `endpage` is no more rendered.

The `endpage` template is defined here: https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/-/blob/master/src/latex/ec/style/beamerthemeec.sty#L19
This is basically the last page of the document with some legal information and the license.

I made a MWE here:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% If you comment the two following lines, you will see the last page of the PDF
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{endpage}{
    \begin{frame}
        The last slide
    \end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Proof of the Main Theorem}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}

  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Try to render this document, you will see that the last frame is not rendered.

Then remove the two lines:

```latex
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}
```

And render again the document, the last frame is there.

So, I'm reaching out here to get some help on this particular issue.

Feel also free to review the theme globally and let me know if I'm doing things correctly, you can find the sources of the theme in this directory: https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/-/tree/master/src/latex/ec/style

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Is there some kind on online platform where I can share some LaTeX src and compile it online ? Some kind of overleaf, but merely like a pastebin ?

Comment: I just added a MWE

Comment: Thanks for adding the MWE to your question, this is by far the best way to share code! Unlike external services, having the MWE directly embedded in your question makes sure that your question keeps being useful for future users with the same problem even if the external resources won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the problem by using `\AddToHook{env/document/end}{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% If you comment the two following lines, you will see the last page of the PDF
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{endpage}{
    \begin{frame}
        The last slide
    \end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\AddToHook{env/document/end}{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Proof of the Main Theorem}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}

  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! How can I do to do that within a beamer theme ?

Can I add this command inside the file https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/-/blob/master/src/latex/ec/style/beamerthemeec.sty ?

Comment: I just tried and it works!

You're a bible, thanks for everything :)

Comment: @PolDellaiera You're welcome!

Comment: Just made a new commit: https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/-/commit/eeab074f64a5b6eb79861a547c2a4851e7ecce50

Comment: @PolDellaiera ... just one tiny detail to keep in mind: hooks need a somewhat newish latex version (I think they were introduced  sometime in 2020, if I remember correctly) If one of your users faces a problem, check which latex version they use.

Comment: Thanks ! But they won't have any issue, we are using Nix, therefore, the LaTeX version is up-to-date and the same for all the users using the theme.

Comment: @PolDellaiera Oh, perfect then :)

Comment: Definitely perfect :) Nix is amazing when it comes to environment reproducibility !

Comment: @PolDellaiera I'd wish one could use it with all beamer users - we would never again have to worry about backwards compatibility in beamer :)

Comment: Nix is getting rid of a whole class of issues indeed... but the learning curve is steep. After 18 months I'm starting to build interesting thing.
The theme(https://code.europa.eu/pol/european-commission-latex-beamer-theme/) I'm building is provided with a Nix integration, any computer running with the Nix program is then able to build documents using LaTeX or Markdown files and have the theme working, feel free to give it a try :) It's just mind blowing !